# Mysql task queue with multiple workers

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I have Mysql database where tasks are inserted. Sometimes they are inserted by 1 or 2 per time, but sometimes they are inserted by 1000 or even more per time. I have workers on multiple servers which are ruled by listeners on these servers. One server = one listener. Listener selects tasks, that are not done yet and that are not in processing right now. It selects an ID of the task and status. If status is empty, then the task is new and we need to proceed id. Then we update the status with an id of server listener (unique) and that means that this server wants to get this task. Then we select tasks using this unique id of the listener and see if there was an attempt of the another listener to do the same at this time. We can see it if the status contains another id. If it is so, we skip the task and continue but if an id is ours we update the status to the processing state indicating our id only if the id in status is ours. After this step we can process the task.
The question is why could happen the situation when some servers process the same tasks? And how to avoid this?

Comment: We can only assume that your process for allocating tasks to servers has a fault in it

Comment: [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, The queries from different listeners can go one by one and at this moment I think we have a gap when first listener has already decided to update the task status and the second is just updating it to it's id and deciding to update it to processig state so there could be such a situation. The question: is it a possible way of interaction and if it is so - how to avoid this? But I'm going to test table locks like in the answer below.